# How to prevent an old crystal report from loading all data without using parameters

Tags: asp.net, .net, crystal-reports, report

In my project, I have lots of Crystal reports that were written long time ago based on database views. They used to work in a VB app where you can specify the sql statement dynamically in the codes by using the SQLQueryString property, the sql statement works as a filter.

Now that I am using crytal report 11 in ASP.NET 4.5, I cannot specify the sql statement any more, thus as soon as I call reportDocument.Load(...), all of the data from the view is loaded, which take minutes to load.

I know that I can add parameters to the reports to solve this problem, but there are so many reports to deal with, is there a way to filter the data without using the parameters? The bottomline is that I don't want to load all data when I call reportDocument.Load

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set report's Record Selection formula